# BigQuery seems to be changing a field from date to bytes when queried

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a scheduled query that executes into google sheets so that we can monitor how many offers we have had through our platform. This used to execute fine until one day I was hit with the error message:

> "BigQuery error: Cannot access field date_created on a value with type
> BYTES at [3:49]"

[image]

The field date_created is a date field in firestore still, so I imagine the problem is with bigquery. What would cause this to suddenly change and make the previously working query to suddenly stop working and how can I fix it?

I would greatly appreciate any help as I can't seem to find any solutions online. Take into consideration that I'm not a developer so please be patient if this is a silly question!

```
SELECT
  Users.profile_data.email as tenant_email,
  Cast (Date(Timestamp_trunc(Offers.application.date_created,DAY)) as DATE) AS offer_date_created,
                    
  Offers.property_id as property_id,
  Offers.status
FROM
  `firestore_daily_replica.users` as Users
INNER JOIN 
  `firestore_daily_replica.tenancy_offers` as Offers
ON(
  Users.uid = Offers.lead_applicant_id
)
ORDER BY
    Offers.application.date_created desc
```

Comment: The syntax looks good to me. In the past this issue appeared in some cases when the exports where surpassing the [column limit](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#column_limit) . Make sure is not your case.

Comment: Hi Aemon4 - many thanks for your response. I believe you are correct that we must have surpassed the 10k column limit - because it was working before, so everything else being constant, the only thing that has changed is the size of the dataset. Will I have to ask the tech team to adjust the database schema if we want to continue extracting info about this timestamp? Is there any way you know of to resolve this within the query?

Comment: Hey Eden, is it working after you ask the tech team to adjust the database schema?